# Interesting identity on $SU(3)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, group-theory

In [arXiv:hep-ph/1307.5414](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.5414) Grabovsky use an interesting identity which is not derived in the paper:
$$\tag{2.30}\varepsilon^{ikm}\varepsilon^{jln}\left((U_{2}U_{4}^{\dagger}U_{1})_{ij}+(U_{1}U_{4}^{\dagger}U_{2})_{ij}\right)(U_{4})_{kl}(U_{3})_{mn}=\\
-B_{123}+\frac{1}{2}(B_{144}B_{324}+B_{244}B_{314}-B_{344}B_{214}).$$
Where:
$$\tag{2.6}B_{123}:=\varepsilon^{ikm}\varepsilon^{jln}(U_{1})_{ij}(U_{2})_{kl}(U_{3})_{mn},$$
which is known as "Baryon". I'm looking forward for some help to derive this identity and generalize it.